# "Brownian motion" without assuming continuity of path at origin of state space

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, counterexamples

This question is inspired partly by this question [Any reference on Brownian Motion continuity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87735/any-reference-on-brownian-motion-continuity). In this post, the author asked if the following three axioms can define a Brownian motion without assuming the continuity axiom

"**4**.$W(t)$ is continuous with probability one. i.e. $\lim _{h\rightarrow 0}P(|W(t+h)-W(t)|>\epsilon )=0,\forall \epsilon>0, t\in S$"
By assuming this, Brownian motion is a special case of Levy process.

> 1. $W(0) = 0$.
> 2. For all $0 \le t_1 \le t_2 \le t_3 \le
>     t_4$, $W(t_2) - W(t_1)$ and $W(t_4) - W(t_3)$ are independent random
>      variables.
> 3. For all $0 \le t_1 \le t_2$ , $W(t_2) - W(t_1)$ is
>      normally distributed with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2\,(t_2 -
>     t_1)$.
>
> [OP](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87735/any-reference-on-brownian-motion-continuity)

In fact, [Karlin&Taylor] defined Brownian motion to be a stochastic process satisfying 1,2,3 axioms with an additional stipulation

"**4***.$W(t)$ is continuous at $t=0$"

And they derived continuity of Brownian path as a result using Karhunen–Loève representation Theorem at Sec 7.4. A possible relevant clue is that we always require the characteristic function $E(e^{Xt})$ to be continuous around origin in order to determine a random variables in distribution via characteristic functions. So I guess axiom 4* is a guarantee that some transform exists?

**My question is that**: If we only assume axiom 1,2,3 on a stochastic process as above, can we construct a stochastic process $W(t)$ that is not a Brownian motion (which is defined as a stochastic process with axiom 1,2,3,4 satisfied OR axiom 1,2,3,4* satisfied in [Karlin&Taylor])? 
OR 
Alternatively, is the continuity axiom redundant? (I do not think so but it does not seem very clear how I can construct a counter example to illustrate the point.)

**After looking at @Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen's answer, I felt a more appropriate question to ask is that if there is a stochastic process that is not càdlàg and satisfies axioms 1,2,3.**

[Karlin&Taylor]Karlin, S., and H. M. Taylor. "A first course in stochastic processes" Academic Press. New York (1975).

Comment: From @BjornKjosHanssen's answer, you see there is a unique version of the process restricted to the rationals; and there is a set of realizations of full measure that is uniformly continuous on this subset. A càdlàg process agreeing with a process like this is precisely Brownian motion.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Yes, that is why I modified my question later. Thanks for you comment :)

Comment: I'm a bit skeptical that the result in K&T is really what you've quoted, since as in Bjørn's answer, you can construct a process satisfying 1, 2, 3, 4*, yet which almost surely has a discontinuity, and it would be very weird for anyone to use the word "Brownian motion" for such a process.  Even 4 is the wrong axiom, since it's also preserved by modifications, so Bjørn's example will also satisfy 4.

Comment: Do K&T also have càdlàg as a standing assumption, or something like that?

Comment: @NateEldredge 4 is copied directly from the linked post as the OP described; To make sure, I looked up K&T, on p.343 Def 2.1 they defined Brownian motion  exactly as a sto. process satisfying 1,2,3,4*. Would you write down your example in mind so that we can discuss? Thanks for your interest

Comment: My proposed example is precisely the first $V_s$ defined by Bjørn: $V_t = W_t$ for $t \ne s$, and $V_s = 0$, where $s$ is independent of $W$ and has, say, a uniform distribution.

Comment: Please ask the nowhere differentiability question in a new question post.  This comment thread is not the place.

Comment: It looks like perhaps K&T address this issue around page 371, though I can't see all the relevant pages in Google Books.  In particular, it might be that "continuous at 0" is defined to mean what others would call "has a modification which is continuous at 0", and that would resolve the issue.

Comment: And also see pp.371-372 of K&T, where they prove continuity by KL method

Comment: But actually, if the definition is "has a continuous modification" then Bjørn's example doesn't work, because it does have a continuous modification, namely $W_t$ itself.

Comment: @NateEldredge I think K&T defined "almost surely continuous path" a bit different from elsewhere(Say Doob or Loeve)  on p .372; But what they mean by continuity at 0 is the same as elsewhere, so I think Bjorn's example still work?

Comment: Karlin & Taylor's approach is a little odd.  Initially, a Brownian motion is a stochastic process whose finite-dimensional distributions are as  in conditions 1,2,3. They remark that the "physical origins of the Brownian motion suggest that the possible realizations of $X(t)$, as graphs of the $x$ coordinate of the position of a particle(i.e., the sample paths) whose movement results from continuous collisions in the surrounding medium are continuous functions." They then proceed to use this presumed sample-path continuity for several sections, proving for example, the reflection principle.

Comment: [continued] Only later (p. 371 ff.) do they deal rigorously with the issue of sample-path continuity, by constructing a stochastic process (using Haar functions) with continuous sample paths and the required finite dimensional distributions.

Comment: @JohnDawkins They do not use it to prove reflection principle, they did not prove it at all in "first course". I think K&T is consistent since they only use continuity of sample path after they derived it in 7.4. I agreed K&T is not very axiomatic in their exposition, but K&T is definitely one of the books on this topic with the fewest typos.

Comment: @Henry.L.: In the version of K&T in front of me (2nd edition, published 1975), they do indeed use path continuity in the discussion on pages 345-351 to find the law of the maximum-up-to-time-$t$ of Brownian motion, and thereby the law of the passage time to a level. Admittedly the "proof" they present for the reflection principle is heuristic (lacking the strong Markov property) but path continuity is crucial, which was the point.

Comment: @JohnDawkins For that one, they do refer to continuity of path since they must use intermediate theorem to argue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, let $W$ be Brownian motion and let $V$ be the following modification:
$V_t=W_t$ except that we pick a number $s\in [0,1]$ according to the uniform distribution, independently of $W$, and let $V_s=0$.

Then 1,2,3 are satisfied but the sample path of $V$ is *almost surely discontinuous* (at $s$).

To get almost sure discontinuity **at 0**, use $s_1,s_2,\dots$ in the unit interval, all $s_i$ independent of each other and of $W$, with say $$V_{s_i}=1\ne 0$$ for all $i$. Note that $S=\{s_i:i\ge 1\}$ is almost surely dense in the unit interval, but $S$ is random relative to $W$ so it will be disjoint from any countable set of $t$'s considered "in advance".

---

**Background**: $W$ will be uniformly continuous on the rationals by axioms 1, 2, 3. But without axiom 4, the question whether the paths are continuous almost doesn't make sense -- the set
$$\{f:f \text { is continuous}\} $$ is not measurable. So one solves this by redefining $W$ to be the unique continuous extension of the values of $W$ on the rationals.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. So it is safe to say removing continuity at origin $X(0)=0$  will cause the same gap due to the increment arguement right? It suffices to define $Y_t=X_{t-s}$ after $s$ is drawn.

Comment: Ok, that is morbid enough and satisfies axiom 1,2,3 since $s_1,s_2,\cdots$ cannot be dense in the unit interval.

Comment: Nate cast some doubts in the comments, and by $\{f:f \text { is continuous}\}$, do you mean the collection of all continuous paths OR the set of continuous points of a given path(I think is the latter)?